# Inputs in python codeforces psets

Tags: python, input

I'm new to python, so at first had some troubles with taking multiple inputs then i learned

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

but still don't know how to take inputs like this.
So how to take inputs in python like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to read from the `sys.stdin` stream instead of using `input()` here:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    numbers = [int(x) for x in line.strip().split()]
    print(numbers)
```

Comment: thank you your way is cool! and i just found another way
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a, m = map(int, input().split())
    lst = list(map(int, input().split()))

Comment: can you break down what exactly does `int(x) for x in line.strip().split()` do?

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a, m = map(int, input().split())
    lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
```